# Write Tridion dreamweaver identifier as output package

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

While working on compound page templating project I have discovered very interesting issue. Customer uses **${stringvalue-session-or-something-specific}** in their custom developed applications that are saved and rendered in component templates using XSLT. When try to render  the component presentations containing reserved Tridion dreamweaver identifier (${}) I have got Template Builder error similar to

> JScriptException: Expression '""["scopedTarget.personalia"]."" != ""' had error 'Expected identifier'
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToObject(String statement)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToString(String statement)

Removing and replacing this identifiers is not solution acceptable by customer.
I was wondering what can be the best solution to cope this issue? Either using C# code to rendering component presentations, maybe create some custom rewrites( if it is possible because I got error from component presentations).

Answer (score 4):

A similar thing happens if customers use JSP EL in their applications, which use the same `${...}` syntax, and want to encapsulate this in their templates.

The most common solution is to replace this syntax with something like `$[...]` in the Dreamweaver templates and use a .Net TBB **after** the Dreamweaver template which uses string replacement or regular expressions to convert it.

See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/4593286) for an example TBB that does this.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use this code to "enable JSTL in templates". Since you can't change Tridion to use a different code identifier, you need to change your markup. Run this TBB at the END of your template to convert `$[expression]` to `${expression}`

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly;

namespace TridionTemplates
{
    [TcmTemplateTitle("Enable JSTL")]
    public class EnableJSTL : ITemplate
    {
        private static readonly Regex JstlRegex = new Regex(@"\$\[.*\]");
        public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
        {
            Item outputItem = package.GetByName(Package.OutputName);
            string outputText = outputItem.GetAsString();
            Match match = JstlRegex.Match(outputText);
            while (match.Success)
            {
                String replaceJstl = match.Value.Replace("[", "{");
                replaceJstl = replaceJstl.Replace("]", "}");
                outputText = outputText.Replace(match.Value, replaceJstl);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
            outputItem.SetAsString(outputText);
            package.Remove(outputItem);
            package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, outputItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is useful in case if layout for both CT and PT are written by DWT. In my case all CT is rendered via old XSLT, and I am creating PT using compound templating. When tried to invoke DWT on component presentations that contains DWT identificators I got the error on @@RendercomponentPresentation@@ step. That implies  that I dont have access to correct output in case if I will use rendering in DWT  and not in C#.

Comment: This suggests that `@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@` is evaluating the result of the Component Template. What version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: Yes, I thought that sounded odd too Nuno. I meant to check the behaviour later. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely can't change the syntax in your Dreamweaver templates (As I stated, I'm not sure I fully understand/agree with the reasons for that) then perhaps you could switch to using the [Razor Mediator](http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/) for your templating instead?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned replacing syntax is not solution. I have solved this by rendering component presentation in separate C# tbb before Dreamweaver template. Off course,David suggestion is useful if you are allowed to change the syntax.

Comment: I understood from your question that replacing the identifiers in the application was not acceptable, but surely replacing them in just the Dreamweaver TBBs is OK. I don't understand why this would be an issue for your customer, as it is the template output that is ultimately published.
I would reiterate that this issue is experienced a lot with JSP applications and that my solution is generally considered best practice. I would strongly advise against rendering layout in c# TBBs.

Comment: Component templates is rendered via XSLT and all identifiers are written with XSLT templates not with Dreamweaver. Just to change this into all existing applications require a lot of time and effort that are not supported from client. I am working on Page templates level where I have to develop new templates based on compound principle. So I have issues how to render component presentation using compound templating where CT is based on XSLT. You are right, rendering layout in C# in not such as good practice but is functional for now...

Answer (score 0):

I use SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1. TemplateBuilder version 6.1 Build 6.1.0.73.
Extract components from Page executed before DWT code below.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
```

@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@

```
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Output error logged from Template builder in case if component presentations contains ${sometext}.

> JScriptException: Expression '""["scopedTarget.personalia"]."" != ""' had error 'Expected identifier'
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToObject(String statement)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToString(String statement)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Package.EvaluateExpression(String expression)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformValueReferences(Package package, StringReference templateReference, Regex startTagExpression, String endTag)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRegions(Package package, String dreamweaverTemplate)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()
>   ---Caused by:
>   Expected identifier
>   eval code: Line 1 - Error: Expected identifier

Comment: I realize that this is an old Q&A, but this should be edited into the question, **not** posted as an answer. (It's currently in the Very Low Quality review queue for not being an answer).